# How do I get data a regular expression does't match?

Tags: php, regex, parsing, preg-match-all

I'm parsing a tweet as a quick way of adding reminders to a database. The tweet would look something like this:

```
$tweet = '#notes @username !high_priority [Project Name] Tweet content';
```

I'm using the following regex to get the #, @, ! and [Project]

```
$match = preg_match_all('/(#\\w*[a-zA-Z_]+\\w*)|(!\\w*[a-zA-Z_]+\\w*)|(@\\w*[a-zA-Z_]+\\w*)|(\\[[^\\]]*\\])/i', 
    $tweet,
    $matches);
```

I want to know how to also get the remaining "Tweet content", so everything that does't match the regex should be saved into a variable.

Also, will the match order matter if the tweet is something more like:

```
$tweet = '@username Tweet content [Project Name] #notes !high_priority';
```

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: What do you think `\w` does? It's pretty much the same as `[a-zA-Z]`

Comment: Just loop through the matches and compose a string out of every match which doesn't start with #, @, ! & [

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the text your regular expression matches with an empty string. What's left is what wasn't matched by the regex.

Comment: I'm using this: 
    `$content = preg_replace('/(#\\w*[a-zA-Z_]+\\w*)|(!\\w*[a-zA-Z_]+\\w*)|(@\\w*[a-zA-Z_]+\\w*)|(\\[[^\\]]*\\])/i', '', $subject);`

and then just trimming the remaining white space.

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_split` instead of `preg_match_all`, then you get all the components in between, as an alternative to Brent's answer which returns a single string. Note that many matches may be empty.

Comment: I typed also an answer to iterate through the matches using `preg_match`, saving the offsets to retrieve the data without copying any strings, but that would be too heavy for this use case. There are multiple ways to Rome I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this code, but I think this non-regex idea might work better for you.  Essentially you split the string by spaces then parse each piece.  This approach means it doesn't matter which order the parts are in.

It gets a little tricky because the content and project can span multiple pieces, but I think my code should handle that. It also assumes that you only have one hashtag, user, project, and priority per tweet.  If there will be multiple hashtags for example, just put them in an array instead of a string.  Lastly, it doesn't have any error handling to detect/prevent weird things from happening.

Here's my untested code:

```
$data = array(
    'hash' => '',
    'user' => '',
    'priority' => '',
    'project' => '',
    'content' => ''
);

$parsingProjectName = false;
foreach(explode(' ', $tweet) as $piece)
{
    switch(substr($piece, 0, 1))
    {
        case '#':
            $data['hash'] = substr($piece, 1);
            break;
        case '@':
            $data['user'] = substr($piece, 1);
            break;
        case '!':
            $data['priority'] = substr($piece, 1);
            break;
        case '[':
            // Check if the project name is longer than 1 word
            if(strpos($piece, -1) == ']')
            {
                $data['project'] = substr($piece, 1, -1);
            }
            else
            {
                // There will be more to parse in the next piece(s)
                $parsingProjectName = true;
                $data['project'] = substr($piece, 1) . ' ';
            }
            break;
        default:
            if($parsingProjectName)
            {
                // Are we at the end yet?
                if(strpos($piece, -1) == ']')
                {
                    // Yes we are
                    $data['project'] .= substr($piece, 1, -1);
                    $parsingProjectName = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Nope, there is more
                    $data['project'] .= substr($piece, 1) . ' ';
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // We aren't in the middle of parsing the project name, and this piece doesn't start with one of the special chars, so assume it is content
                $data['content'] .= $piece . ' ';
            }
    }
}

// There will be an extra space on the end; remove it
$data['content'] = substr($data['content'], 0, -1);
```

Comment: BTW you may need to double-check my usage of substr.  I'm using it to check the first char, last char, and grab everything except for the first or last char.  I hope it makes sense and works :P

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an error in your RegEx as you use \w before [a-zA-Z_] which looks like you wanted to match whitespace whereas \w matches word-characters. You could do it that way (for this little part):

```
...\\s*[\\w_]+\\s*...
```

As you already seem to loop over the matches to get the different parts, you could create a sub-pattern for the plain-text you want to match and or-connect it with the rest of your pattern. This way you would just have one additional match. This would work for a different order of the contents aswell as long as you differentiate between the matched parts while looping over the matches.